# InvalidMutabilityException on IOS with mutable variables using coroutines in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I simplified the error, and I just have this class:

```
class TestClass{
    private var string = "Hello"

    fun testError() {
        string= "It Works"
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            string = "Doesn't work"
        }
    }
}
```

If I launch TestClass().testError() on the main thread (on IOS), it throws an InvalidMutabilityException (at line --> string = "Doesn't work"). So I thought that maybe it's not a good idea to change the variable on a thread other than the one that created the variable. So I changed to this:

```
class TestClass{
    private var string = "Hello"

    fun testError() {
        string= "It Works"
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { string = "Doesn't work" }
        }
    }
}
```

but it still throws an error:

kotlin.native.concurrent.InvalidMutabilityException: mutation attempt of frozen com.example.project.TestClass@fe10a8

By the way. Both codes above work on Android side

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kotlin/Native has a different threading model than the JVM. `TestClass` gets frozen when the data is captured in the lambda. The `string` assignment silently captures the parent `TestClass` and freezes it.

See the following:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/concurrency.html
- https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Kotlin%20Native%20Concurrency/00_Introduction
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxQ6e1VeH4M

Comment: Awesome talk of Kevin Galligan! Helped a lot! Thanks